# Modify SVN branch point

Tags: svn

Is it possible to rewrite the history of a SVN repo that has subtree branches and tags from trunk so that all branches and tags contain "complete" copies of trunk? If so, how?

For example:

```
  branches
    module1-feature1
    module1-feature2
    trunk-branch1
      module1
      module2
      module3
    trunk-branch2
      module1
      module2
  trunk
    module1
    module2
    module3
```

In the above example the module1-feature1 branch only contains the code for module1. I want it to contain the folder called module1 and also the folder module2 (and the folder module3 if it existed when the branch was created). The name of the branch is not important, but the contents should be a complete copy of the trunk at the time, not just the subfolder that the branch was created from. All changes on that branch will be inside of the folder module1, obviously.

Comment: By rewrite do you mean recreate all revisions since the branchpoint with the full code, or do you mean change the tree now to graft everything together? The latter is easier; you can just copy `trunk@revision` and then move the changes into place. The former will be possible by e.g. filtering a repo dump, but I don't know of a tool that supports this; you might need to code something up yourself.

Comment: I mean recreating all revisions since the branch point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the branch point is actually quite simple, once you know how. However, you need an SVN dump to perform the changes and then load that into a new (or reset) repository.

I used Ubuntu for this procedure, but I am no Linux expert, so forgive me for possible errors.

Step 1. Get server-side access to the SVN repo

If you don't have access to the server-side of the SVN repo, you need to create a local copy of the repo:

```
 svnadmin create repo_name
 cd repo_name
 cp hooks/pre-revprop-change.tmpl hooks/pre-revprop-change
```

Edit the file pre-revprop-change so that it always does exit 0 at the end.

```
 chmod a+x hooks/pre-revprop-change
 svnsync initialize file:///path/to/repo http://url.to.repo
 svnsync synchronize file:///path/to/repo
```

Step 2. Create the dump file

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repo > repo.dump
```

Step 3. Modify the dump (it's a good idea to make a copy first)

Since branching in SVN only involves committing a reference to the original data, moving the branch point up is actually quite simple (in theory). At some point in the dump file you will have something like this:

```
Node-path: branches/module1-feature1
Node-action: add
...
Node-copyfrom-path: trunk/module1
```

Changing that record into:

```
Node-path: branches/module1-feature1
Node-action: add
...
Node-copyfrom-path: trunk
```

is a good start, but now all subsequent changes to that branch will be wrong. Therefore, all changes made to files in the `branches/module1-feature1` tree should really be in the `branches/module1-feature1/module1` tree. This can be accomplished using search and replace on affected paths (I used sed for this).

Note that, if you have mergeinfo records you should update these as well to get the branches to merge properly. For example:

```
mergeinfo   
K 13
svn:mergeinfo
V 19
/trunk/module1:2267
```

should become:

```
mergeinfo   
K 13
svn:mergeinfo
V 11
/trunk:2267
```

The number after the V must equal the length of the following line. This is not so easy to do with search and replace. If the length is wrong, the dump cannot be imported and you'll get an error.

As long as you have **never made any branching mistakes** in the history of the SVN repo, this is all you need.

However, in practice, I found that I had to use a combination of three different approaches.

1. Manual edits for a few cases where the branching were done in a way that required me to remove an entry entirely. I used emacs, but it is important to use an editor that you trust not to change bytes that you haven't touched.
2. svndumpfilter for removing irrelevant things in the dump.
   I needed svndumpfilter for the GIT migration (if you're making multiple GIT repos from a single SVN-repo you can use svndumpfilter to clean out the stuff that is irrelevant to the repo your currently creating). It was also useful to cut down the size of the dump and make it more comprehensible. Also, I had some temporary branches that I no longer cared about at all, that were also difficult to correct.
3. Automated search and replace as described above.

Step 4. Load the dump file and check for errors

Create a new repo using the following commands:

```
svnadmin create /path/to/repo
svnadmin load /path/to/repo < repo.dump
```

Check the messages printed when loading the repo to make sure it is correct. I didn't find a good way to check the new SVN repo directly, but since I was going to migrate to GIT anyway, that wasn't a problem I spent any time trying to solve.

Step 5. Convert into GIT (bonus)

I used Atlassian's SVN migration scripts to get an authors file (https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/svn-migration-scripts/downloads/svn-migration-scripts.jar) which I then corrected.

Git migration was then done using Subgit.

Comment: Neat. You should be able to use some of the dump compression features to save a bit of time streaming it in and out. I'd also thought you should modify svndumpfilter to do the commit patch changes for you rather than just use sed to avoid accidentally catching other instances of the strings in the dump, but it sounds like you got away with sed.

Comment: It seems like a good idea to modify svndumpfilter, but I don't know how.